# gdalwarp on County-wide mosaic or COG takes forever or seems to hang

Tags: gdal, gdalwarp, imagery, orthophoto

I am creating Cloud Optimized GeoTIFFs using gdal from a folder of TIFF files in GDAL for an entire county. After creating a mosaic of these files (in EPSG:6551) using `gdalbuildvrt` I can create a COG from the mosaic in a few days, maybe 3-5. The output is amazing - small file size and crisp imagery. However, when I try to use `gdalwarp` to re-project the imagery, either the mosaic or the COG, to WebMercator the process starts, writes a small amount of data, but then appears to hang, though gdalwarp is still consuming memory and CPU.

I am wondering if there is a way to either a) debug gdal to make sure it is not hanging and is indeed running, or b) to speed up the warp process. I am already using all the maxcache, multi, NUM_THREADS settings I can find. I also tried to warp each TIFF individually, which works but creates transparent artifacts in the end product on the edges of the individual TIFF files.

It may be that this is the best I can expect from an 8th Gen i5 with 6 Cores and 32GB ram...

Warp settings

```bsh
-et 0 -overwrite -wo NUM_THREADS=ALL_CPUS -multi -r lanczos ^
```

COG Settings

```
-of COG -co RESAMPLING=CUBIC -co COMPRESS=JPEG -co BIGTIFF=YES -co NUM_THREADS=ALL_CPUS -co QUALITY=85 ^
--config GDAL_CACHEMAX 9999 ^
--config GDAL_NUM_THREADS ALL_CPUS
```

Comment: While not an answer to this particular problem, I am going to try and use the `-tap` setting along with various `-tr` settings along side warping each tiff file. These ideas came from here - https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/107903/holes-between-imagery-tiles-projected-using-gdalwarp.

Comment: Try without `--config GDAL_CACHEMAX 9999 `, usually it just makes things slower by forcing GDAL to keep bigger cache than it really needs. Using -tap for individually warped images is a good idea.

Comment: -tr did not solve the transparent artifacts between tiffs.

Comment: I wonder if it has to do with JPEG compression. I understand that it is not an option for your whole task but you could make a test with handful of tiffs by using lossless compression "deflate". And `-tr` was not what is important but `-tap`, target aligned pixels. Option is normally used with `-tr`, but I suppose that's what you did.

Comment: One more option could be to warp the VRT or COG into biggish rectangular tiles by using `-projwin`. Find out how large area can be converted in a reasonable time. There may be logarithmic grow in time/area ratio.

Comment: Well it looks like warping the whole county might take about 2x as long as simply using gdal_translate to create a COG. I'm at 10% over 24 hrs, but the final 20-30% doesn't take as long. Anyway the issue with warping anything but the entire county is you end up with transparent bands on the edges of the each TIFF. I did think about doing them in batches, that way each batch could complete in maybe 24hrs or so. I think the biggest issue is not having enough single core compute power to perform the warping, that and the read/write disk speeds which are not great (standard HDD).

Comment: Unless I hear otherwise this will be the answer: gdalwarp is resource heavy so get the fastest CPU and disk you can afford.

Comment: I have produced a seamless mosaic from thousands of individually warped original tiffs so I know that at least it has been possible with my source data, that certain GDAL version, and commands. That service is not up anymore and I do not remember all details. What I remember is that both the original and warped versions were uncompressed. You are right that for warping each pixel must be read, processed, and written so it is heavy.